# How to collapse rows with individual, contiguous dates into single rows with date range start and end

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, group-by, sql-server-2019, gaps-and-islands

Given a data set like this:

| Id | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 100 |
| 1 | 01/02/2021 | 100 |
| 1 | 01/03/2021 | 100 |
| ... | ... *(rows omitted for brevity)* | ... |
| 1 | 12/29/2021 | 100 |
| 1 | 12/30/2021 | 100 |
| 1 | 12/31/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 01/02/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 01/03/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 06/01/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 06/02/2021 | 100 |
| 2 | 06/03/2021 | 100 |

Is it possible to write a query to return a result set where each row is a contiguous date range, grouped by the `Id` column? Like this:

| Id | Start Date | End Date | Sum of Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01/01/2021 | 12/31/2021 | 36500 |
| 2 | 01/01/2021 | 01/03/2021 | 300 |
| 2 | 06/01/2021 | 06/03/2021 | 300 |

I'm imagining it will be some combination of window functions and group bys, but I'm not even sure it's possible and didn't want to fumble towards a solution that didn't exist.

I'm using SQL Server 2017 and 2019, if that matters.

The date ranges can be long - months or years. For example, one of the collapsed rows could be a year long, coming from 365 individual rows, like in the given example.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH 
cte1 AS ( SELECT Id, xDate, Value,
                 CASE DATEDIFF( DAY, LAG(xDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY xDate), xDate ) 
                 WHEN 1 
                 THEN 0
                 ELSE 1 END delta
          FROM test ),
cte2 AS ( SELECT Id, xDate, Value, SUM(delta) OVER (ORDER BY Id, xDate) grp
          FROM cte1 )
SELECT Id, MIN(xDate) startDate, MAX(xDate) endDate, SUM(Value) sumValue
FROM cte2
GROUP BY id, grp;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f733343fa3043af2e5a76f0d3d82f7e1)